# Issues calculating the area of a polygon in C

Tags: c, arrays, polygon, scanf, area

Attempting to calculate the area of polygon that takes (x,y) coordinates up to a possible 100 points from .txt file using redirection e.g. ./program < file.txt
I'm having trouble scanning in the input so that my function will calculate the area.
The input is:

```
3 12867 1.0 2.0  1.0 5.0  4.0 5.0
```

Where 3 is the npoints and 12867 is the identification number.
This is my code I have produced so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_PTS 100
#define MAX_POLYS 100
#define END_INPUT 0

// function to calculate the area of a polygon
// think it's correct
double polygon_area(int MAX_PTS, double x[], double y[])
{
  printf("In polygon.area\n");
  double area = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PTS; ++i)
  {
     int j = (i + 1)%MAX_PTS;
     area += 0.5 * (x[i]*y[j] -  x[j]*y[i]);
  }

  printf("The area of the polygon is %lf  \n", area);

  return (area);
}

// having trouble reading in values from a txt file into an array

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int npoints, poly_id;
  double // something should go here 

  if(scanf("%d %d", &npoints, &poly_id)) {
    int iteration = 0;
    struct Point initialPoint = a;
    double area = 0;  
    scanf("%lf %lf", &, &); 
    // keep getting errors with what goes next to the & 

    for (iteration = 1; iteration < npoints; ++iteration) {
        scanf("%lf %lf", &, &); 
        // keep getting errors with what goes next to the & 
        area += polygon_area(); // unsure what to do here

    }
    // now complete the polygon with last-edge joining the last-point
    // with initial-point.
    area += polygon_area(a, initialPoint);

    printf("First polygon is %d\n", poly_id);
    printf("area = %2.2lf m^2\n", area); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I happen to be a newbie to coding so anything past using arrays and structs I won't really understand, but any help is still appreciated!

Comment: please tell more about npoint and identification number . What is its use? where are the (x,y) co ordinates?

Comment: I doubt `scanf("%lf %lf", &, &);` will compile. This should at least read `&a.x, &a.y` or something compatible with the definition of Point.

Comment: You can't use `MAX_PTS` as a #define and an argument name. It will not work as the compiler will see your variable name as 100, which is an illegal variable name.

Comment: `"keep getting errors with what goes next to the &"`: well, that makes a lot of sense, considering the fact that there is nothing next to the `&` in your code!!!

Comment: Just a tip, if you don't _have_ to use C, use something else. Python for instance is much easier for simple tasks like that.

Comment: @JunaidShirwani the npoint just details the number of (x,y) coordinates, and the identification number is poly_id which is just details which polygon is being used. The (x,y) coordinates start after poly_id and i.e. (1.0, 2.0), (1.0, 5.0) etc...

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I know it won't compile and I appreciate what needs to be read but I don't really understand why and what needs to be. Care to elaborate?

Comment: `float x;` is a variable. As a function argument `printf("%lf", x)` `x` would _evaluate_ as e.g. 1.0. Adding the ampersand `&` one will instead evaluate `&x` as the _address_ of _x_, allowing the function `scanf` to _write_ to the variable. Without this paradigm one would be restricted to constructs such as `x = scan_float(); y = scan_float();` where a function can never return (or modify) more than one parameter. `&a.x, &a.y` would give the _variadic_ function `scanf` addresses of both attributes of the struct Point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already looping for reading the vertices. First read all the vertices, and then calculate the area. That is to say, you should not call polygon_area in a loop. Here is a code piece with the fixes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_PTS 100
#define MAX_POLYS 100
#define END_INPUT 0

// function to calculate the area of a polygon
// think it's correct
double polygon_area(int length, double x[], double y[])
{
    double area = 0.0;
    int i;
    printf("In polygon.area\n");
    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        int j = (i + 1) % length;
        area += (x[i] * y[j] - x[j] * y[i]);
    }
    area = area / 2;
    area = (area > 0 ? area : -1 * area);
    printf("The area of the polygon is %lf  \n", area);

    return (area);
}

// having trouble reading in values from a txt file into an array

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int npoints, poly_id;
    double x[MAX_PTS], y[MAX_PTS];
    int iteration = 0;
    double area = 0;

    scanf("%d %d", &npoints, &poly_id);

    for (iteration = 0; iteration < npoints; ++iteration) {
        scanf("%lf %lf", &(x[iteration]), &(y[iteration]));
    }
    area = polygon_area(npoints, x, y); // unsure what to do here

    printf("First polygon is %d\n", poly_id);
    printf("area = %2.2lf m^2\n", area);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't "require to use C", here's my take on it using C++ (and Boost).

Note this has lots of other features, and corrects the input to adhere to the required invariants.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c356827c0eed4a4)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/area.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/correct.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/io.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace bg = boost::geometry;

using Point   = bg::model::d2::point_xy<double, bg::cs::cartesian>;
using Polygon = bg::model::polygon<Point>;

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
    template <>
    struct assign_to_attribute_from_value<Point, fusion::vector2<double, double> > {
        static void call(fusion::vector2<double, double> const& t, Point& attr) {
            attr = Point(fusion::at_c<0>(t), fusion::at_c<1>(t));
        }
    };
} } }

int main() {
    Polygon poly;

    int npoints, poly_id;

    if (
            (std::cin >> npoints >> poly_id) &&
            (std::cin >> std::noskipws >> qi::phrase_match(qi::repeat(npoints) [qi::attr_cast(qi::double_ >> qi::double_)], qi::blank, poly.outer()))
       )
    {
        bg::correct(poly);
        std::cout << "Polygon: " << bg::wkt(poly)  << "\n";
        std::cout << "Area: "    << bg::area(poly) << "\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
}
```

For the given input it prints:

```
Polygon: POLYGON((1 2,1 5,4 5,1 2))
Area: 4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

*edit:* I'm sorry, I'm using command line parameters here, not redirection as you wanted. You can still use it like: `./program $(cat test.txt)` in bash syntax.

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    //argc contains the number of parameters.
    //argv[0] is the filename of the executable
    //argv[1] has your npoints
    int npoints = atoi(argv[1]);
    //argv[2] has your poly_id
    int poly_id = atoi(argv[2]);
    double *x;
    double *y;
    x = malloc(sizeof(double)*npoints); //allocate space
    y = malloc(sizeof(double)*npoints);

    //convert the command line parameters
    for (i=0;i<npoints;i++) {
        x[i] = atof(argv[i*2+3]);
        y[i] = atof(argv[i*2+4]);
    }

    //print them again, remove this and do your calculations here
    for (i=0;i<npoints;i++) {
        printf("%f %f\n", x[i], y[i]);
    }
}
```